# How can I use gcc g++ to compile a windows binary if I am running on a Linux OS?

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, g++, cross-compiling

I am working on a project where I have to compile a program which is to run on Windows 7 computers. I only have a Linux computer, so I borrow a friends computer to compile the program before emailing it to the client. Then the client comes back to me with requested alterations, etc.

Can I compile the program for Windows using gcc/g++ for Linux?

Comment: Wait, you are planning to send completely untested software to a client? Seriously?

Comment: You want to have a look at the MinGW environment: http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: VirtualBox or one of the other virtualization solutions.  If you compile on linux, how would you possibly test your changes?

Comment: Not untested, these are just version updates. All sections of the software are working and tested on windows and linux. Now we are just tweaking the output file formats. There is no possible way that it works on Linux and then will not work on Windows

Comment: Also virtualbox isn't a solution - no windows os disk

Comment: If this is just about version updates, then you don't need a compiler. A linker is sufficient to link your version resource together with the object code to output a binary image. [COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) is a standard file format (even though Linux felt that following standards is too damn tough).

Answer (score 0):

try MingW http://www.mingw.org/. perhaps it solve your problem